# Mobile tracking using SSL

Tags: android, ios, ssl, user-tracking

I have a mobile app (Android/IOS) which can track the end user on field. I want to secure the communication between the mobile app and the `REST` server. So I plan to use `SSL` for this. Is it the recommended to handle such critical info when we consider to send these locations every 100 meters (more or less)?

If yes should we open a `SSL` connection all the times we send a single location or should open and keep a long (I do not know how long) `SSL` session in order to send the locations?

If not then what is the fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an app like that.
The user not always has Internet.
The user very probably want to upload the data only, when is connected to WI-FI.
My solution it was to store the data encrypted with AES in NDK side inside the app ( private data ) upload to server -without hassle of SSL encrypted of course.

At the server side it was dencrypted.

The server will send a confirmation to phone the decrypt process status, optionally: done / failed.

Comment: I think you are right!!! We use it on another project where we cannot use SSL and where we need to encrypt data.